# Visual Studio Code + Cygwin always starts new instance

Tags: editing

I've found a strange issue with Visual Studio Code (tested with 1.23).

I have an instance of VS Code already running. Now when I open a file from the command-line, the behavior is different depending on the shell I use:
1) when I use the Windows cmd shell, the file is opened in the existing VS Code instance (which is what I actually want)
2) when I use the Cygwin shell, the file is always opened in a new instance of VS Code, and this does not change even if I use the -reuse-window switch, and my settings should also be correct: "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off", "window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow": "off"
3) when I use the Windows cmd shell from within a Cygwin shell, I get the same (for me unpleasant) behavior as in 2)

For me, it looks as if VS Code does not find the existing instance from within Cygwin, but it does find the existing instance from the Windows cmd shell...

Best,
Ralph